# How to add smb service to run level?

Tags: fedora, samba

I want smb start with system. Do i have to place script that start smb in etc/rc.d/rc6.d/ or there is a way to make it listed in autostart services after `#chkconfig smb on` ?
 The question is why if i do as prescribed  `#chkconfig smbd on` this help my for a few launches of system, and eventually samba daemon stops again?

```
# chkconfig --list

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

dund            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
livesys         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
livesys-late    0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
pand            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
rfcomm          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
spice-vdagentd  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:on    6:off
```

this output don't change despite of chkconfig --level 5 smb on
I need every start do in terminal `#systemctl restart smb.service` to get samba work 
one more circumstance i get this strange output

```
# ps aux |grep smb
root       859  0.0  0.1  25328  3184 ?        Ss   15:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd
root       863  0.0  0.0  25844  1244 ?        S    15:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd
```

when samba share don't work 
and after samba manual restart  i get this

```
# ps aux |grep smb
root      1729  0.0  0.1  25328  3184 ?        Ss   15:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd
root      1731  0.0  0.0  25844  1244 ?        S    15:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd
nobody    1732  0.0  0.1  25632  3072 ?        S    15:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd
```

a bit more info on subject

```
#systemctl list-unit-files --type=service |grep smb
smb.service                                 enabled 
# systemctl list-unit-files --type=service |grep avahi
avahi-daemon.service                        enabled 
# systemctl list-unit-files --type=service |grep nmb
nmb.service                                 enabled
#chkconfig --version
chkconfig version 1.3.59
```

To avoid mannualy typing each restart samba daemon start commands i made a desktop launcher for lxde fedora enviroment in ~/Desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=mc
Name[en_US]=setsmb
Icon=share_32
Exec=/usr/bin/lxterminal -e "su root -c 'systemctl restart smb.service && systemctl restart nmb.service'"
```

Comment: Just a note, runlevel 6 is usually *reboot* and thus starting something in it won't do much good. Usually runlevels 0 and 6 just shut down everything.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'chkconfig' command to list the samba service automatically start on all runlevel.

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list smb
```

The 'chkconfig' command below enable the samba server to start on runlevel 5.

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --level 5 smb on
```

Verify the configuration change.

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list smb
```

Comment: this method i tried. Please look at my refurbished question.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in chkconfig-1.3.52-1.fc15 (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693500). Updating chkconfig may solve it.

Comment: my chkconfig --version say that is 1.3.59 fc17